# 301 in htaccess is not redirecting

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have the htacess file in the root of a WordPress website (http://www.raynauds.org).  I need to redirect all calls to:

http://www.raynauds.org/?p=2366

to:

http://www.raynauds.org/2012/08/11/dr-maureen-mayes-joins-raynauds-association-medical-advisory-board/

I am running Apache on a Linxus Server.  The code below seems to be doing nothing to redirect the request.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
Redirect 301 /?p=2366 http://www.raynauds.org/2012/08/11/dr-maureen-mayes-joins-raynauds-association-medical-advisory-board/
```

Comment: Is AllowOverride On set in your apache config?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite and Redirect are both applied to the URL before looking for the file to be executed.

Your RewriteRules both have the [L] flag stating that this will be the last Rule to modify the URL, so the Redirect will not be used for URLs matching one of the RewriteRules.

As the second RewriteRule will catch all requests your Redirect will not work.
You can also redirect with a RewriteRule like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p=2366
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Please also look at the available flags in the [Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Of course this rule should go before RewriteCond/RewriteRule lines of Wordpress itself to work.

Comment: Thanks... That makes sense.  The 301 redirect does not seem to work with a query string.  When I removed the query string and use a straight url, the 301 worked (as long as it was above the Base).

Comment: Can you upload your current .htaccess code (with Dehalion's answer in it) to pastebin.com, and then post a link here so we can check it?

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Redirect 301` rule to the line below the `RewriteBase` statement.

Comment: That did not work..  It did work if I just put a URL in there without the query string.  The problem seems to be with the query string in the 301.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd suggest Dehalion's answer may be a better solution.